# Definition of a function of a real variable

Tags: real-numbers

Wikipedia says that

> a function of a real variable is a function whose domain is the real numbers $\mathbb R$, or a subset of $\mathbb R$ that contains an interval of positive length.

I don't understand what it means for a subset of $\mathbb R$ to have an interval of positive length. Does this mean that the subset cannot have only integers since this particular subset would be just points on a number line and not a length on the number line? What if the subset of $\mathbb R$ was $\{1,2\}\cup[3,4]$? Is this a valid subset? It has 2 points and a length on the number line but the only condition is that the subset has an interval of positive length so it seems that this is a valid subset of $\mathbb R$. Also, what is the point of saying "positive length"? Why can't the definition of a function of a real variable just say "length"?

Comment: Have you seen measure theory? Measure theory rigorously defines what it means for a set to have positive "length" or measure, and is only undefined on very pernicuous sets.

Comment: The set you proposed has length $1$. So yes, it is valid. They simply don't want to deal with sets of length 0.

Comment: @DonThousand no I'm only in calc 2 rn

Comment: The definition is stipulating positive length as opposed to zero length. The interval $[a,a] = \{a\}$ is an example of a (degenerate) interval of zero length.

Comment: Yes, that is valid.  What wouldn't be valid is a domain of $\mathbb Q$.  An interval "of positive length" means there is some $x,y; x< y$ so that $(x,y)$ is a subset of domain. Now you might wonder how there can be an interval of zero or negative length and that's fair.  But some text would consider the set $\{x\}$ to be an interval of zero length (depends on the text). I think to idea is that the real numbers, as opposed to the radicals has continuum and so a real function must have *some* continuum interval; it can be a *really* small space of continuum but it must exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the definition provided on Wikipedia.

> A function of a real variable is a function whose domain is the real numbers $\mathbb R$, or a subset $D\subseteq\mathbb R$, which contains an interval of positive length.

This means that the function $f$ is called a function of a real variable if and only if $f:D\to E$ for some set $E$ (common examples are the real numbers $\mathbb R$ or the complex numbers $\mathbb C$), where the domain $D$ is  a subset of $\mathbb R$ and in addition, $D$ has a subset $(a,b)\subseteq D$ so that $b>a$. Here, the "length" of an interval of the forms $(a,b),[a,b],[a,b),(a,b]$ are all defined to be $b-a$. So by "positive length" we mean that the length $(b-a)>0$, i.e. $b>a$. The reason we need to make this definition is because usually, we consider sets of the form $[a,a]=\{ a\}$ as intervals too. But of course, this set has zero length.

In your example, the domain $D=\{1,2\}\cup[3,4]$ does satisfy this criterion, because the interval $[3,4]\subset D$ is an interval of positive length (in particcular, it has length $1>0$). On the other hand, sets like the rational numbers $\mathbb Q$ but also more "pathological" sets like the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) can be shown to contain no intervals of positive length, and will not therefore suffice as an example of the domain of a real variable, as it is defined on Wikipedia. The formal definition of this is in terms of measures, specifically the [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure), which formalises the idea of lengths. The Lebesgue measure of the Cantor set is $0$ [see [here]](https://math.unm.edu/~crisp/courses/math402/spring16/CantorSet.pdf), so that it does not contain an interval of positive length.

The reason we often impose the restriction that $D$ has an interval of positive length is because we often want to study changes in $f$ around the *neighbourhood* of a particular point $x$ in the domain. We want to ask questions you might have seen in Calculus, such as "if we change $x$ by a little bit, how much does $f(x)$ change?". We can do so if there is a connected set (i.e. an interval) to deal with. But if our set looks like $D=\mathbb Q$ for example, it makes our life harder. So we exclude those sets from definition just so that we don't need to think about them.